# Getting Specific values from an xml using xsl

Tags: xslt

I have an xml as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is a complete, yet short and easy transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="attributeName[.='salience']">
  <salience>
   <xsl:value-of select="../value"/>
  </salience>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<attributes>
    <attribute>
        <attributeName>agenda-group</attributeName>
        <value>common</value>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <attributeName>auto-focus</attributeName>
        <value>true</value>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <attributeName>no-loop</attributeName>
        <value>true</value>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <attributeName>salience</attributeName>
        <value>73</value>
    </attribute>
</attributes>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<salience>73</salience>
```

Comment: I have tried the above Approach.But its not working for me.But i have tried the below solution which is working for me but dont know whether this is optimized solution or not.                                                                   YOur help would be appreciated.Please find my below solution

Comment: @srinivas: Just copy and paste the transformation, then run *it* on the XML document you provided -- you must get the wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <xsl:template match="attributes/attribute">
    <xsl:if test=".//attributeName='salience'">
      <xsl:value-of select=".//value"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

*P.S. Please format your post, as the XSL is not showing.*

Comment: The above solution is not working.I am getting nothing in the output file.

Comment: Take note of `<xsl:template match="attributes/attribute">`. It is different from what you have. I have tried this and it worked. Please double check how you implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is this **xsl:if** statement

```
<xsl:if test="//attributes//attribute[(attributeName = 'salience')]">
```

At this point, the context is still the root node, so all this does is checking the existing of an **attibute** element, you are not actually positioning yourself on the node. Thus, when you do the **xsl:value-of** you are simply getting the first **value** in the XML.

Instead of using an **xsl:if**, you should probably try matching the **attribute** element, like so

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="attributes/attribute[attributeName = 'salience']"/>
```

The whole XSLT would be as follows

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="attributes/attribute[attributeName = 'salience']"/>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="attribute">
      <xsl:element name="{attributeName}">
         <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied on your input XML, the output is as follows:

```
<salience>73</salience>
```

Note the use of **xsl:element**

```
<xsl:element name="{attributeName}">
```

This avoids having to hard-code **salience** in your matching template, making it more generic should you wish to match other elements in a similar fashion.